# Problems with Js displaying in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with JS not changing the HTML in the 3rd function could anyone tell me why or tell me how to change this code to work?

```js
               

function chosen() {
                    var x = document.getElementById("a").value;
                    if(x == 1) {
                        document.getElementById("aa").innerHTML = "Acura years arent available right now";
                        document.getElementById("ab").innerHTML = "";
                    } else if(x == 3) {
                        document.getElementById("aa").innerHTML = "<div class='input-group mb-3'><div class='input-group-prepend'><label class='input-group-text' for='inputGroupSelect01'>Year</label></div><select class='custom-select' id='b' id='inputGroupSelect01' oninput='Year()'><option selected disabled>Year</option><option value='1'>1987</option></select></div>";   
                    }
                        }
                function Year() {
                    var y = document.getElementById("b").value;
                    var x = document.getElementById("a").value;
                    if(y == 1) {
                        if(x == 3) {
                           document.getElementById("ab").innerHTML = "<div class='input-group mb-3'><div class='input-group-prepend'><label class='input-group-text' for='inputGroupSelect01'>Class</label></div><select class='custom-select' id='c' id='inputGroupSelect01' oninput='l()'><option disabled selected>Select a class</option><option value='1'>190D</option></select></div>";
                        } else if(x == 1) {
                           document.getElementById("ab").innerHTML = "Unavailable";
                        }
                    }}
                function l() {
                    var z = document.getElementById("c").value;
                    var y = document.getElementbyId("b").value;
                    var x = document.getElementbyId("a").value;
                    if (x === 3 && y === 1 && z === 1) {
                        document.getElementById("ac").innerHTML = "input schematics here";
                    }
                }
```

```html
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Brand</label>
  </div>
  <select class="custom-select" id="a" id="inputGroupSelect01" oninput="chosen()">
    <option selected disabled>Select Brand of car</option>
      <option value="1">Acura</option>
      <option disabled value="2">Alfa Romeo</option>
    <option value="3">Mercedes Benz</option>
    <option value="4">Toyota</option>
    <option value="5">Lexus</option>
    <option disabled value="6">Volvo</option>
    <option value="7">Fiat</option>
    <option disabled value="8">Porsche</option>
    <option value="9">BMW</option>
      <option disabled>options are limited b/c Im Lazy lol</option>
            </select></div><h6 id="aa"></h6><h6 id="ab"></h6><h6 id="ac"></h6>
```

Side note: I used **Bootstrap 4.0**
You can also find out how it works in this webpage Bigbn.oyosite.com

Comment: Possibly the strict comparison, try changing the `===` to `==` as you have in other areas.

Comment: There is one issue you use multiple `id` to element which is not right. also as said @PaulT. due to strict mode. its causing to enter inside if case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one issue you use multiple id to element which is not right. also as said comment. Due to strict mode. its causing to enter inside if case

```js
function chosen() {
  var x = document.getElementById("a").value;
  if (x == 1) {
    document.getElementById("aa").innerHTML = "Acura years arent available right now";
    document.getElementById("ab").innerHTML = "";
  } else if (x == 3) {
    document.getElementById("aa").innerHTML = "<div class='input-group mb-3'><div class='input-group-prepend'><label class='input-group-text' for='inputGroupSelect01'>Year</label></div><select class='custom-select' id='b'  oninput='Year()'><option selected disabled>Year</option><option value='1'>1987</option></select></div>";
  }
}

function Year() {
  var y = document.getElementById("b").value;
  var x = document.getElementById("a").value;
  if (y == 1) {
    if (x == 3) {
      document.getElementById("ab").innerHTML = "<div class='input-group mb-3'><div class='input-group-prepend'><label class='input-group-text' for='inputGroupSelect01'>Class</label></div><select class='custom-select' id='c'  oninput='l()'><option disabled selected>Select a class</option><option value='1'>190D</option></select></div>";
    } else if (x == 1) {
      document.getElementById("ab").innerHTML = "Unavailable";
    }
  }
}

function l() {
  var z = document.getElementById("c").value;
  //console.log(document.getElementById("a").value);
  var y = document.getElementById("b").value;
  var x = document.getElementById("a").value;
  if (x == 3 && y == 1 && z == 1) {
    var thirdElem = document.getElementById("ac");
    thirdElem.innerHTML = "input schematics here";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group-prepend">
  <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Brand</label>
</div>
<select class="custom-select" id="a" oninput="chosen()">
  <option selected disabled>Select Brand of car</option>
  <option value="1">Acura</option>
  <option disabled value="2">Alfa Romeo</option>
  <option value="3">Mercedes Benz</option>
  <option value="4">Toyota</option>
  <option value="5">Lexus</option>
  <option disabled value="6">Volvo</option>
  <option value="7">Fiat</option>
  <option disabled value="8">Porsche</option>
  <option value="9">BMW</option>
  <option disabled>options are limited b/c Im Lazy lol</option>
</select>
</div>
<h6 id="aa"></h6>
<h6 id="ab"></h6>
<h6 id="ac"></h6>
```

Answer (score 1):

You had 3 problems in your code:

1. Why did you write === instead of == in 3rd function? x, y, and z are strings so type conversion is needed. please use == instead of ===. Please read this to understand the difference between === and ==: [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)
2. You used 2 ids in 1 element that will work but it is incorrect.
3. You can find the main problem by going to browser dev tools. when it starts to run function `l()`, it makes an error. you wrote this for `x` and `y`

```
var y = document.getElementbyId("b").value; //It errors getElementbyId is not a function because you used lower case b in by
var x = document.getElementbyId("a").value;
```

You used getElement**by**Id instead of getElement**By**Id

In conclusion, Your code will work if you change `by` to `By` and `===` to `==`. But using 2 ids is also incorrect but it will not make any error but it's better to change that.
Hope this helped you.

Comment: This is details about strict operator. Upvoting you explained.

Comment: i used `===` because JSLint told me to do that

Comment: Mahan lameie, I originally used `==` but that did not seem to work so i instead used `===`

Comment: @Bruhh111 I improved my answer and tested your code and now these changes will make your code work and it contains all of 3 major problems in the code.